# My ID is not being applied

Tags: html, css

I am working on a project and I basically copied and pasted some code I had made before that I know worked. The only difference is that now, the `index.html` and `index.css` is in a different folder. The CSS is being applied but the `ID`'s at the bottom are not for some reason. Still, if you preview it on this website, it is completely fine.

```css
/*
font-family: 'Dosis', sans-serif;
font-family: 'Chewy', cursive;

HEX: #fff2df
HEX: #d9ad7c
HEX: #a2836e
HEX: #674d3c
*/

body {
  font-family: 'Dosis', sans-serif;
  background: #fff2df;
}


/* Matan's Website */

h1 {
  font-family: 'Chewy', cursive;
  font-size: 65px;
  text-align: center;
}


/* Line */

hr {
  width: 600px;
  border-style: solid;
  margin-top: -15px;
}


/* All Boxes */

ul {
  overflow: hidden;
  text-align: center;
}

li {
  float: center;
  text-align: center;
  display: inline-block;
}

a {
  background-color: #000;
  border-radius: 20px;
  z-index: 100;
}

.buttons {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
}

.links {
  font-size: 37.5px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
}


/* Individual Boxes */

#word {
  background-image: url('Pictures/word.jpg');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: 50% 50%;
  padding: 162.75px 119.25px;
  margin: 65px 75px 0px 0px;
  color: #fff;
  transition: all 0.5s ease-out;
}

#word:hover {
  padding: 189.875px 139.125px;
  transition: all 0.5s ease-out;
  opacity: 0.8;
  margin-right: 63.4px;
  margin-left: -28.125px;
  margin-top: 37.875px;
}

#pwpoint {
  background-image: url('Pictures/powerpoint.jpg');
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  padding: 162.75px 69.75px;
  margin: 65px 75px 0px 0px;
  color: #fff;
  transition: all 0.5s ease-out;
}

#pwpoint:hover {
  padding: 189.875px 81.375px;
  transition: all 0.5s ease-out;
  opacity: 0.8;
  margin-right: 63.275px;
  margin-left: -11.5px;
  margin-top: 37.875px;
}

#ptshop {
  background-image: url('../Pictures/photoshop.jpg');
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  padding: 162.75px 99px;
  margin: 65px 0px 0px 0px;
  color: #fff;
  transition: all 0.5s ease-out;
}

#ptshop:hover {
  padding: 189.875px 115.5px;
  transition: all 0.5s ease-out;
  opacity: 0.8;
  margin-right: -28.125px;
  margin-left: -4.9px;
  margin-top: 37.875px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Portfolio</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../index.css">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Chewy|Dosis" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>
  <h1>My Portfolio</h1>
  <hr>
  <div class="allbuttons">
    <ul class="buttons">
      <li><a class="links" id="word" href="Word/index.html">Word</a></li>
      <li><a class="links" id="pwpoint" href="Powerpoint/index.html">Powerpoint</a></li>
      <li><a class="links" id="ptshop" href="Photoshop/index.html">Photoshop</a></li>
      <li><a class="links" id="other" href="Other/index.html">Other</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

None of the IDs work, but the CSS file is linked correctly and displayed correctly. Any ideas why this might be?

Comment: For clearance, the path to the css is correct?

Comment: @Swellar yes. all the css but the id's are being applied.

Comment: It looks like it is working in the snippet

Comment: @Swellar I know. This is why I am so confused. Any ideas why?

Comment: Is it possible that another stylesheet is interfering with your result on your production server?

Comment: Try using hard refresh *(`Ctrl + R`)*

Comment: @FredGandt maybe. I have tons of index.css named files but they are all in different folders. this index.html file has the correctly linked css file. Its very weird that only the ID's are not getting applied.

Comment: Have you tried a hard refresh yet? It's a good suggestion to start off with.

Comment: @FredGandt yes. nothing is helping.

Comment: OK, now try using an absolute URL to the CSS - starting with `http(s)`.

Comment: @Redhart nope. Everything looks just like its supposed to.

Comment: @FredGandt I am using a file on my computer. This is not live on the web yet.

Comment: I highly recommend installing and using a localhost server for development work. I use [XAMPP](https://www.apachefriends.org/download.html) (free and nice). But for now, just make the path to the file complete, to eliminate the possibility of that being an error (as you say, you have lots of other files by the same name).

Comment: @FredGandt still nothing. also, if the path to the file was not complete the rest of the css wouldn't show up. the problem is every css selector but the ids show up. very weird.

Comment: "if the path to the file was not complete the rest of the css wouldn't show up" unless the rules are being picked up from the file you copied this one from. I am just trying to eliminate the possible issues we here cannot see, but that might exist. As the snippet shows, there is no reason for the `id`s to not have the rules applied, so it *must* be a configuration issue.

Comment: @FredGandt that solved my problem. thank you very much for your help.

Comment: If you have any comments in the file on your computer, make sure they're closed correctly. I know this seems obvious, but I've wasted hours looking for solutions when all that was missing was a semi-colon or comma (these things happen).

Comment: @FredGandt yep. I know what you mean. I checked everything through and I just needed to add a folder to the css link on the html. thank you.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/146920/discussion-between-matan-berkovsky-and-fred-gandt).

Answer (score 1):

## "Eliminate all other factors, and the one which remains must be the truth."

As Sherlock Holmes [frequently pointed out](https://en.wikiquote.org/wiki/Sherlock_Holmes), when searching for the truth (in this case, a solution) we must first eliminate the clutter.

[Relative *vs.* Absolute URLs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Path_(computing)#Absolute_and_relative_paths) are convenient when accurate, but prone to error for [a variety of reasons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2005079/absolute-vs-relative-urls).

A tidy workspace is invaluable; when coding any project, create and maintain [a controlled and suitable space](https://www.apachefriends.org/index.html) to help with avoiding and diagnosing problems that might crop up.

...

Other mildly patronising platitudes are available on request ;-)